# Import a ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have a **Agent** class model

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)     
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)     
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And I have a **AgentList** class model

```
class AgentList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    agents = models.ManyToManyField(Agent)
```

What I want is when I click the "Import" button in my admin get a page with two field :

- Select the CSV (with the registration_number, first_name, last_name)
- Write a name for the list

All agent will be saved in Agent and it will make a new "AgentList" link to those I imported.

I already try some custom import page, but I'm starting to think it exist a better way.

ATM my AgentListAdmin look like this :

```
@admin.register(AgentList)
class AgentListAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name",)
    filter_horizontal = ("agents", )

    def get_dataset(self, file):
        """
        Returns the dataset from the uploaded file.
        """
        dataset = tablib.Dataset()
        try:
            dataset.load(file.read().decode('utf-8'), format='csv')
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValidationError(str(e))
        return dataset

    def import_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Import action.
        """
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = forms.Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                file = request.FILES['file']
                dataset = self.get_dataset(file)
                result = self.process_dataset(dataset, request=request, confirm_form=None)
                if result.has_errors():
                    self.message_user(request, result, messages.ERROR)
                else:
                    self.message_user(request, result, messages.SUCCESS)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
        else:
            form = forms.Form()

        context = self.admin_site.each_context(request)
        context.update(
            {
                'form': form,
                'opts': self.model._meta,
                'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
            }
        )

        return render(request, 'admin/import_agent_list.html', context)
```

but I also need to custom the process_dataset and it feels like I'm customing everything...

I saw this thing in the official documentation:
https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#customize-admin-import-forms

And I guess I need something like this...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a lot of code as per your example.  You can customize import forms using the example in the [documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#customize-admin-import-forms).  Therefore you only add customization to your ModelAdmin and Resource.

You can create whichever form fields you need on the custom form.

You can pass these to the Resource so that you can update any instances created or read from persistent storage.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77089017/39296).