# django-import-export Customize Admin Missing Field Error

Tags: django, django-import-export

I am using django-import-export to manage csv uploads.  I have the following import working vanilla and now want to extract the 'league' and 'season' fields from the .csv and instead choose them via form fields in the admin interface.  I am able to select values but when I submit I receive the following error:

> Line number: 1 - (1048, "Column 'league_id' cannot be null")

I followed the code example here: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#customize-admin-import-forms

Here's the relevant code:

```
# admin.py

class TeamsSeasonResource(resources.ModelResource):
  # https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_usage.html#importing-model-relations
  ballpark = fields.Field(
    column_name='ballpark',
    attribute='ballpark',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Ballpark, field='park_name'))
  team = fields.Field(
    column_name='team',
    attribute='team',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Team, field='team_acronym'))
  league = fields.Field(
    column_name='league',
    attribute='league',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(LeaguesSeason, field='id'))
  season = fields.Field(
    column_name='season',
    attribute='season',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Season, field='season_year'))

  class Meta:
    model = TeamsSeason
    import_id_fields = ('ballpark', 'team', 'season', 'league')


class TeamsSeasonAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('id', 'season','team')
  resource_classes = [TeamsSeasonResource]
  import_form_class = TeamSeasonImportForm
  confirm_form_class = TeamSeasonConfirmImportForm

  def get_confirm_form_initial(self, request, import_form):
    initial = super().get_confirm_form_initial(request, import_form)
    # Pass on the value from the import form to
    # the confirm form (if provided)
    if import_form:
      initial['league'] = import_form.cleaned_data['league']
      initial['season'] = import_form.cleaned_data['season']
    return initial

  pass
admin.site.register(TeamsSeason, TeamsSeasonAdmin)
```

```
# forms.py

from django import forms
from import_export.forms import ConfirmImportForm, ExportForm, ImportForm
from .models import *

class TeamSeasonImportForm(ImportForm):
    league = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=LeaguesSeason.objects.all(),
        required=True)
    season = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Season.objects.all(),
        required=True)


class TeamSeasonConfirmImportForm(ConfirmImportForm):
    league = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=LeaguesSeason.objects.all(),
        required=True)
    season = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Season.objects.all(),
        required=True)
```

If I submit the .csv with the fields removed, I receive the error.  If I submit the .csv with the 'league' and 'season' fields in there, I am able to successfully submit but the form fields in the admin are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that because you have defined 'league' as a Field, it is looking for these values in the csv, hence why it works when the fields are in the csv.

The docs aren't completely clear, but if you want to access the form values, you need to add this to your custom admin class:

```py
def get_import_data_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Return form data as kwargs for import_data.
    """
    form = kwargs.get('form')
    if form:
        return form.cleaned_data
    return {}
```

This means that the form values are then passed onto the import process.

You'd then have to set the values onto each created (or retrieved) model instance.  You can do this by overriding this method on your TeamsSeasonResource:

```py
def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, row_number=None, **kwargs):
    instance.league = kwargs["league"]
    instance.season = kwargs["season]
```

Then the values should be set correctly when the instance is persisted.

I can't guarantee I've got this completely correct, you might need to step through with the debugger to ensure it's working correctly.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the fix, it worked perfectly once those two methods were overridden.